# How i can stop the code after opening a dialog box?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, each

I got a problem with my code :

```
        $("#lbCreer").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("input:checked").each(function () {
                var id = this.value;
              $("#hdId").val(id);
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            });
            alert('toto');
        });
```

I'd like to stop the each after opening the dialog box. How i cant do it?

Thanks

Comment: You could `return false` after dialog open to break out of the loop, but then why do you need a loop if you want to break out after opening the dialog?

Comment: I open the dialog box then the user confirm sothing and on when the user click on the ok button i do a process. I wannt do it for all check box cheked. I not sure about my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sequence the execution, but you cannot use loop do that. See below example to get an idea of how to sequence.

```js
var $dialog;
$(function() {
  $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [{
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        if ($selectedCheckboxes != null && $selectedCheckboxes.length > 1) {
          $selectedCheckboxes = $selectedCheckboxes.slice(1);
          updateDialog();
        } else {
          $message.text('Processing complete, dialog will close in 5 seconds');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $dialog.dialog("close");
          }, 5000);
        }
      }
    }]
  });

  var $message = $('#dialog .message');

  function updateDialog() {
    $message.text('processing ' + $selectedCheckboxes.get(0).value + ' now, click Ok to start next');
  }

  var $selectedCheckboxes = null;
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $selectedCheckboxes = $('input:checked');
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    updateDialog();
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget {
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" media="screen, print" />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Red" checked="checked" />Red</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Green" checked="checked" />Green</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Blue" checked="checked" />Blue</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Black" />Black</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="White" />White</label>
<button id="button">Check</button>
<div id="dialog" title="My Dialog"><span class="message">Loading, please wait...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll try your sequence

Comment: @Eric Welcome to Stackoverflow. For closure, Please accept it as an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the code :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            draggable: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    var fok = $('#montantrecu').validationEngine('validate');
                    if (!fok) {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Services/Services.asmx/Facture")%>',
                            data: "{'IdMembre':'" + $('#hdId').val() + "', MontantFacture': '" + $('#montantrecu').text + "' }",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false,
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert("Ok");
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert("failure");
                            },
                            error: function (request, status, error) {
                                alert(request.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                "Annuler": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#lbCreer").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("input:checked").each(function () {
                var id = this.value;
                $("#hdId").val(id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Services/Services.asmx/GetNomPrenom")%>',
                    data: "{'IdMembre':'" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#liNom").text(response.d);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("failure");
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(request.responseText);
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Services/Services.asmx/GetMontantCotisation")%>',
                    data: "{'IdMembre':'" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#montantrecu").val(response.d);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("failure");
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(request.responseText);
                    }
                });
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            });
            alert('toto');
        });
    });
```